# Is it possible to create a PubSub setup with Python 2 and Python 3 simultaneously?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, legacy

Here's the idea: the publisher is using Python 2, and the subscriber is using Python 3.

The goal is to break out legacy Python 2 code into Python 3 modules, and to communicate using a publisher subscriber model.

I've tried a prototype using PyPubSub but it seems it doesn't work.

py2publisher.py:

```
import time
from pubsub import pub


while True:
    print("Sending message")
    pub.sendMessage("topic", payload={'type': 'video', 'path': '/idk/idk/idk'})
    pub.sendMessage("topic", payload={'type': 'screenshot', 'path': '/idk/idk/idk2'})
    time.sleep(1)
```

py3subscriber.py:

```
from pubsub import pub

def topic_listener(payload):
    print("Received payload type: ", payload['type'])
    print("Payload path: ", payload['path'])

pub.subscribe(topic_listener, 'upload')
```

With python 2 in venv and python 3 in venv 2:

```
./venv2/bin/python py3subscriber.py
./venv/bin/python py2publisher.py
```

I believe it doesn't work because the package versions are different, and the implementation of PyPubSub doesn't use something that might be more agnostic to versions like a websocket server/client

Comment: Why dont you try and let us know?

Comment: "I've tried a prototype using PyPubSub but it seems it doesn't work."

Comment: OK - I get it.. Why dont you use a Message Queue like Rabbit  MQ?

Comment: I'll check it out. Would there be any implementations use only well known packages? No offense to Rabbit MQ, I've just never heard of them